# SetItemState doesnt mark automatically

Tags: c++, function, mfc

Ive made a search function for my List Control in Report View in my MFC Dialog. It looks like this

```
m_List.SetItemState((m_List.FindItem(&Finde)),LVIS_SELECTED,LVIS_SELECTED );
```

It searches the Content that is in the Variable `Finde` and marks it. Now it should mark the row. But I first have to click somewhere in the program. It doesnt mark the row directly after the function gets called.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the full function

```
LVFINDINFO Finde;
Finde.flags = LVFI_PARTIAL|LVFI_STRING;
Finde.psz = _T("Siffert");
if ((m_List.FindItem(&Finde)) != -1)
{
    m_List.SetItemState((m_List.FindItem(&Finde)),LVIS_SELECTED,LVIS_SELECTED ); 
    //m_List.SetSelectionMark((m_List.FindItem(&Finde)));
}
else
{
    MessageBox(_T("No Results"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the style [LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Otheriwse the selection is only shown when the control has the focus and is active.

EDIT: Also keep in mind that there is also a LVIS_FOCUSED style, that also forces scrolling to this item.

Comment: Is there a way to activate it?

Comment: What to activate? The style can be set in the dialog editor. Or you use the style in your CreateWindow(Ex) code.